# Fastest way to draw from a distribution many times

Tags: julia

This:

```
function draw1(n)
    return rand(Normal(0,1), Int(n))
end
```

is somewhat faster than this:

```
function draw2(n)
    result = zeros(Float64, Int(n))
    for i=1:Int(n)
        result[i] =  rand(Normal(0,1))
    end
    return result 
end
```

Just curious why that is, and if the explicit loop way can be speeded up (I tried `@inbounds` and `@simd` and didn't get a speedup). Is it the initial allocation of `zeros()`? I timed that separately at about 0.25 seconds, which doesn't fully account for the difference (plus doesn't the first way pre-allocate an array under the hood?).

Example:

```
@time x = draw1(1e08)
  1.169986 seconds (6 allocations: 762.940 MiB, 4.53% gc time)
@time y = draw2(1e08)
  1.824750 seconds (6 allocations: 762.940 MiB, 3.05% gc time)
```

Comment: Have a look at definition of `_rand!(s::Sampleable{Univariate}, A::AbstractArray)` in Distributions package and you will see that it actually performs a loop.

Comment: Everybody seems to have overlooked `randn` which basically does the same for this specific distribution. `draw6(n) = randn(n)` is fastest on my machine (but not significantly)

Answer (score 3):

Try this implementation:

```
function draw3(n)
    d = Normal(0,1)
    result = Vector{Float64}(Int(n))
    @inbounds for i=1:Int(n)
        result[i] =  rand(d)
    end
    return result 
end
```

What is the difference:

- uses `@inbounds`
- creates `Normal(0,1)` only once
- performs faster initialization of `result`

When I test it it has essentially the same performance as `draw1` (I have not tested it on 10e8 vector size though (not enough memory) - if you can run such `@benchmark` it would be nice):

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools                        

julia> @benchmark draw1(10e5)                      
BenchmarkTools.Trial:                              
  memory estimate:  7.63 MiB                       
  allocs estimate:  2                              
  --------------                                   
  minimum time:     12.296 ms (0.00% GC)           
  median time:      13.012 ms (0.00% GC)           
  mean time:        14.510 ms (8.49% GC)           
  maximum time:     84.253 ms (81.30% GC)          
  --------------                                   
  samples:          345                            
  evals/sample:     1                              

julia> @benchmark draw2(10e5)                      
BenchmarkTools.Trial:                              
  memory estimate:  7.63 MiB                       
  allocs estimate:  2                              
  --------------                                   
  minimum time:     20.374 ms (0.00% GC)           
  median time:      21.622 ms (0.00% GC)           
  mean time:        22.787 ms (5.95% GC)           
  maximum time:     92.265 ms (77.18% GC)          
  --------------                                   
  samples:          220                            
  evals/sample:     1                              

julia> @benchmark draw3(10e5)                      
BenchmarkTools.Trial:                              
  memory estimate:  7.63 MiB                       
  allocs estimate:  2                              
  --------------                                   
  minimum time:     12.415 ms (0.00% GC)           
  median time:      12.956 ms (0.00% GC)           
  mean time:        14.456 ms (8.67% GC)           
  maximum time:     84.342 ms (83.74% GC)          
  --------------                                   
  samples:          346                            
  evals/sample:     1
```

EDIT: actually defining a loop in a separate function (exactly as `rand` does) gives a bit better performance of `draw4` than `draw3`:

```
function g!(d, v)
    @inbounds for i=1:length(v)
        v[i] = rand(d)
    end
end

function draw4(n)
    result = Vector{Float64}(Int(n))
    g!(Normal(0,1), result)
    return result 
end
```

Answer (score 3):

A shorter answer is that the built-in implementation is fastest, which is fortunately often the case.

Instead of `draw4` above, you could just use the inbuilt

```
function draw5(n)
   result = Vector{Float64}(Int(n))
   rand!(Normal(0,1), result)
end
```

Filling an existing vector with something like `rand!` will always be inbounds.